# Eclipse with Tomcat does not automatically republish my WAR file

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, deployment, tomcat6, eclipse-kepler

I've got Windows 8.1 with a 1.6 JDK manually installed.

I'm using Eclipse (Kepler, Java EE IDE for Web Developers).
I imported a project that builds a `WAR` file using an `Ant` build script; that shows up as a Project.
I created a Tomcat6 `Server` (downloading the available Eclipse package); that shows up as a second Project.

On the `Modules` tab for the `Server`, I clicked "Add External Web Module...", browsed to the folder holding my `WAR` file and clicked OK.  I then added the name of my `WAR` file (directory name "...\SpiffyApp" to file name "...\SpiffyApp\spiffyapp.war").  I confirmed that the name of the path is "/"; I clicked to have "Auto reloading enabled" checked, and clicked OK.

I admit - I peeked inside the `Server` configuration.  I clicked on "Open launch configuration"; in dialog "Edit launch configuration properties", on the Arguments tab, I discovered the following property setting:

> > -Dcatalina.base= "....metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0"

Then in my mischief I observed that the "tmp0" directory had a "webapps" subdirectory.  Aha!

I notice that, under some circumstances, the "SpiffyApp" is republished under "webapps" - problem is, I can't figure out *when*!

Specifically, I'm disappointed that Eclipse doesn't republish my app to "webapps" when I tell the server to "Clean"/"Publish".  What I'd *really* like is for it to republish automatically when I rebuild the `WAR`.

I can get the `WAR` redeployed when I do all of this:

1. stopped my Tomcat `Server`
2. delete all folders under "tmp0/webapps"
3. delete all folders under "tmp0/work" (tip I got from [Chris Lercher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291741/chris-lercher), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980689/tomcat-creates-web-inf-lib-but-doesnt-explode-war-files-gwt))
4. rebuilt my `WAR` file
5. Started my `Server`

Surely I'm doing something wrong.

What are the rules here?  Am I really left to remove the Web Module, delete the folder in "tmp0" and re-add the Web Module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is expecting it to watch for changes on an archive file, which generally isn't expected to change. Import the WAR as a project and then Eclipse can deploy it properly when something actually changes within the app.

Otherwise you might try forcibly Cleaning the server area from the context menu of the Tomcat server instance in the Servers View.

Comment: Sadly, as I mentioned, Clean/Publish from Tomcat didn't redeploy the webapp.

Long term, I need to do what you said.

Short term, I was hoping to give my customer simple instructions to debug their already-built archive.  They have a legacy build procedure, to run an Ant script in an "IDE for Java Developers" Eclipse package.

You've answered my question - thanks @nitind!