# war deployed to webapp but directory created has no content

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web-applications, java-server

appl.war is deployed to webapp folder of Tomcat. when server started I can see below line in server log :
...Deployment of web application archive appl.war has finished in 181 ms.

Also the appl directory created but do not see any content in it.

Hence when I browse giving the context root /appl I get error message that "page cant be displayed".

What is going wrong any idea ?

Comment: The issue in my case is that of permission. The Linux account i am suing to start the server does not have permission to create the files/folder. Hence getting exception while expanding the war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem sounds similar to the stackoverflow link below,

[Tomcat creates WEB-INF/lib but doesnt explode war files (GWT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980689/tomcat-creates-web-inf-lib-but-doesnt-explode-war-files-gwt)